# Trying to install Redis, but having a hard time

Tags: ubuntu, redis, terminal

redis-server -v on terminal gives the output:
Redis server v=7.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.1 bits=64 build=68bf11aad5b039df

But whenever I run node on terminal and const redis = require("redis"), it outputs MODULE NOT FOUND.

Im on Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the npm redis package?
npm i redis

Comment: Same error again, MODULE NOT FOUND

Comment: Is it well defined in the "dependencies" of  your package.json?